# Prestashop 1.7.7.5 installation issue : ps_facebook1

Tags: installation, https, centos, mariadb, prestashop

On Centos8, issue during installation of Prestashop 1.7.7.5 (also with 1.7.7.4) :

[Installation issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSkbs.png)

An error occurred during installation...

ps_facebook1: Cannot install module "ps_facebook"

Tried lot of things but nothing works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a temporary workaround:

- After you get the error delete content of ps_facebook module folder
  (**delete the content, not the folder!**)
- Change folder permission to 400
- Try installing again